# gimp colour level algorithm

Tags: algorithm, colors, bmp, gimp

My first question on this forum, please be soft with me :)

I have a bunch of BMP files (created by the script i wrote ) and i would like to change the color level of them. 
Currently, i open Gimp, i go to "color level" set the input level values from 0~255 to 200~255 , i click "ok" and i get what i want. 
But i would like to understand what is the algorithm behind that, so that i can code it. 
I tried to search , i read the Gimp documentation but i did not find enough information. If someone could help, that would be great !

Thanks a lot for you help :)

Comment: Create a bmp with pixels set to all values from 0 to 255 (greyscale or for RGB seperately), process with Gimp, then check the resulting values; this should tell you all you need to know

Comment: Of course i did that - Results are not consistent.  i suspect some RGB to HSL translation and something else... but what ?

Comment: Isn't Gimp open source? You could check the code itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first googled ling  shows documentation https://docs.gimp.org/en/gimp-tool-levels.html

If you don't need gamma correction (middle slider), use simple linear transformation, where V and NV is old value and new (corrected) value for ever color channel (R, G, B), L and H are Low and High levels.

```
 NV = Min(255, Max(0, (V - L) * 255 / (H - L)))
```

Comment: Thank you for the link, i did find it too... However, the formula you wrote is not part of this documentation , isn't it ?  May i ask where you found it ? Thank you !

Comment: I make formula from thinking that transformation should transform L value 0, H value to max (255), and it is linear .

Comment: I just tested your algorithm and it worked. Thanks! Keep in mind that if `H = L` then it will fail due to a divide-by-zero, though.